# Plot 10 highest bars with ggplot2 instead of 70 bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

For my assignment I have a dataset of Olympic Medal Winners and need to make a stacked bar chart. I currently have the following plot.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = medalwinners, aes(x = Team, fill = Medal)) +
  geom_bar()
```

My data:

```
structure(list(Name = c("Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen", "Giovanni Abagnale", "Patimat Abakarova", 
    "Luc Abalo", "Luc Abalo", "Jeremy Abbott" ), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), 
  Age = c(28L, 21L, 21L, 27L, 31L, 28L), 
  Height = c(184L, 198L, 165L, 182L, 182L, 175L ), 
  Weight = c(85, 90, 49, 86, 86, 70), 
  Team = c("Finland", "Italy", "Azerbaijan", "France", "France", "United States"), 
  NOC = c("FIN", "ITA", "AZE", "FRA", "FRA", "USA"), ), 
  Medal = c("Bronze", "Bronze", "Bronze", "Gold", "Bronze")), ., 
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
  class = "data.frame")
```

How can I adjust the plot so that it shows barcharts for the top 10 countries for example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, it would be useful to see a snippet of your data in order to help you. Currently, we have no idea what `medalWinners` looks like. Please consider posting the output of `dput(head(medalWinners))` for us to have a look.

Comment: This is what it looks like!

```structure(list(Name = c("Juhamatti Tapio Aaltonen", "Giovanni Abagnale", 
"Patimat Abakarova", "Luc Abalo", "Luc Abalo", "Jeremy Abbott"
), Sex = c("M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M"), Age = c(28L, 21L, 21L, 
27L, 31L, 28L), Height = c(184L, 198L, 165L, 182L, 182L, 175L
), Weight = c(85, 90, 49, 86, 86, 70), Team = c("Finland", "Italy", 
"Azerbaijan", "France", "France", "United States"), NOC = c("FIN", 
"ITA", "AZE", "FRA", "FRA", "USA"), 
), Medal = c("Bronze", "Bronze", "Bronze", "Gold", 
"Bronze")), ., row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first calculate the the number of medals won by any team and sort them from high to low, and subset the dataset to the top 10.

```
medals_perteam <- sapply(split(medalWinner, medalWinner$Team), nrow)
medals_perteam <- sort(medals_perteam, decreasing = TRUE)
# Replace [1:3] by [1:10] for top 10 instead of top 3
topmedals <- medalWinner[medalWinner$Team %in% names(medals_perteam)[1:3],]
```

And then we could plot this subset of data:

```
ggplot(data = topmedals, aes(x = Team, fill = Medal)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I recently found an easy way to make a subset 
of a ggplot here is an example, "test" is just the ggplot object
then the last row is the useful stuff.

```
test.1 <- 
    ggplot(data = test, aes(x = Team, fill = Medal)) +
    geom_bar() 
test.1

# Get the name of the Teams greater than 10
n.1 <- table(test.1$data$Team) %>% .[.>1] %>% names()

# pipe subset into ggplot
test.1 %+% subset(test.1$data, Team %in% n.1 )

# or pipe a subset of a df into ggplot
test.1 %+% (test.1$data %>% group_by(Team) %>% filter(n()>1))
```